# Divergent sums and substraction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I have been thinking on this fact. The harmonic sum is divergent, but if I take the sum with N terms and subtract the $ln(N)$, the limit is finite when N goes to infinity ($\gamma$).

How can this be generalized to other series? Is there a formal theory?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course I mean beyond the cases in which the sum with N terms can be explicitely calculated.

Comment: I don't believe there is much of a generalization. All that is done is showing that the limit is finite and then approximating it. I believe it's just using the theory behind convergence of limits.

Comment: That is also my guess... But maybe we can be surprised! :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Cutting off" a divergent series at some point, estimating the "partial sum", then subtracting off the "divergent part" to obtain a finite limit is indeed one way of "summing" (regularizing) divergent series. We of course need to define what we mean by the terms in quotes, though. Terry Tao wrote a [great blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) about this specific topic.